# Is MPI_Reduce also does the work of MPI_Barrier?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi, numerical-computing

As MPI_Reduce and MPI_Barrier are costly commands, so I have to reduce some communication among threads.
I know the main work of MPI_Reduce and MPI_Barrier.
Sometime I observed that MPI_Reduce is reducing all values in one threads as well as it is also doing the work of MPI_Barrier. Is it possible that if I have to use mpi_Reduce then I can skip MPI_Barrier?

Answer (score 3):

No, `MPI_Reduce()` does not implicitly perform `MPI_Barrier()`.

That being said, `MPI_Allreduce()` (with non-zero size data) performs an implicit `MPI_Barrier()`, so that might be a fit for your algorithm.

I am not quite sure of what you mean by *`MPI_Barrier()` is a costly operation*. Assuming you have a decent interconnect, the barrier itself should be pretty fast, and most of the time spent should be caused by process imbalance.